Apache2.4 LDAP authentication suddenly not working
We have a web interface that configures through API calls a load balancer cluster. That web interface makes use of three (python) scripts. The first script displays the current settings of the load balancer, the second one displays a menu with which the settings can be changed, and the third script will configure the chosen settings and does some logging. As most users are only interested in the settings, that script can be accessed by anyone. For accessing the second and third script, we require the user to be authenticated. The first script resides in <root>/cgi-bin/RO, the second and third are in <root>/cgi-bin/RW. The directory permission on <root>/cgi-bin/RO is Require all granted. The ldap config and the directory permission for <root>/cgi-bin/RW are:
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap LDAP>
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVC_APIACCESS,OU=Service Accounts,OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=BEHEER,DC=example,DC=org"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://1.2.3.4 6.7.8.9/OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=APPS,DC=ont,DC=example,DC=org?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>


<Directory "/<root>/cgi-bin/RW">
  Options +ExecCGI
  Require valid-user
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Enter LDAP credentials"
  AuthBasicProvider LDAP
  AuthUserFile /dev/null
</Directory>

The idea is to capture the REMOTE_USER setting after successful authentication, and use that in the logging for auditing purposes in case of problems. When accessing the second script, a pop-up would appear asking for username and password. After successful authentication the configuration page is shown.
This used to work. For some reason, that pop-up asking for authentication is no longer shown, and the script terminates prematurely at the point where the variable that used to contain the value of REMOTE_USER is accessed. The odd thing is no logging is produced, no error seems to be thrown when the script tries to access an undefined variable, selinux does not log any policy violation, nor does httpd log the failure to contact the ldap servers. Does anyone has an idea as to what's happening here?

You are using a plain text (unencrypted) LDAP connection. I'll save you the lecture about sending passwords in the clear on the network, but maybe your AD administrator noticed and enforced "bind over a security connection only" ? Can you still log in at the command line with ldapsearch or with a few lines of Python ?

@ixe013, no, insecure connections are still possible. I've tried using ldapsearch with the credentials of the account that's used by Apache, and that works fine. I've had a tcpdump running when accessing the RW-page, no ldap traffic was seen. So it seems that the "require valid-user" statement is ignored as unauthenticated users can access that page.

Is <IP 1> <IP 2> in your questions 2 different IP addresses used for load-balancing ?  If that's the case, please update your question with made up ip address (1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8) or made up hostnames (ldap1.example.com and ldap2.example.com).

@ixe013, not necessarily load balancing, rather for high availability. Changed the placeholders to fake ip adresses as you mentioned.

The fact that you are not seeing any traffic to your LDAP servers probably means the AuthLDAPURL is not parsed as we think it is.
You added a space to separate your two LDAP hosts, as the documentation suggests, but maybe you should create two aliases as suggested in the AuthCore module examples:
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap LDAP-region-A>
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVC_APIACCESS,OU=Service Accounts,OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=BEHEER,DC=example,DC=org"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://1.2.3.4/OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=APPS,DC=ont,DC=example,DC=org?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap LDAP-region-B>
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVC_APIACCESS,OU=Service Accounts,OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=BEHEER,DC=example,DC=org"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://6.7.8.9/OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=APPS,DC=ont,DC=example,DC=org?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>


@ixe03, tried it, no luck...

Well, after going through some cycles of trying and giving up, I got it to work again.
As mentioned above, there is a <root>/cgi-bin/RO directory that unauthenticated users can access, and a <root>/cgi-bin/RW directory, there you can make changes,that only authenticated users should be able to access.
I got it to work by removing "Require all granted" from <root>/cgi-bin. I now only have "Require all granted" for the <root> directory, and "Require valid-user" for the <root>/cgi-bin/RW folder.
Side note: if you need to restrict access to certain AD groups, you have to use the AuthzProviderAlias construct. Putting in "Require ldap-group <group identifier>" does not work, you have to put "Require <alias>" in, where <alias> is of course the alias you defined in the AuthzProviderAlias construct.
